# Проблемы со свободным количеством inode

Tags: файловая-система, ext4

С помощью df -ih я могу увидеть сколько inode доступно на диске. Но проблема в том что на диске много папок и подпапок. Соответственно, как мне одной командой посмотреть в какой папках очень много занятых inode?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ очень простой. Одно команда решает проблему
du --inodes /boot/